# Get Sphinx to autodoc my Cython class's __init__

Tags: cython, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have this Cython class:

```
cdef class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, someargument):
        pass
```

And I want Sphinx to document it like this:

> *class* **Sprite**(*self, texture*)
>       Does stuff.

so I tried documenting it:

```
cdef class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, someargument):
        """__init__(self, someargument)

        Does stuff."""

        pass
```

But it didn't even show up. I even tried this:

```
cdef class Sprite:
    """Sprite(self, someargument)

    Does stuff."""

    def __init__(self, someargument):
        pass
```

This time it did show up, but sphinx didn't do it's magic stuff with this information like it normally does:

> *class* **Sprite**
>       Sprite(self, texture)
>       Does stuff.

So how must I do it?

Comment: Perhaps your problem is related to insufficient docstring support: http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html?highlight=docstring#docstrings

Comment: @mzjn: False, `import pygrafix; pygrafix.sprite.Sprite.__doc__` gives me `"Sprite(self, texture)\n\nblablabla"`.

Comment: What does the ReST source look like? Does `pygrafix.sprite.Sprite.__init__.__doc__` give you anything?

Comment: @mzjn: it's a sphinx bug, apparently.

Comment: OK, maybe it is a bug. But instead of referring to Sphinx's "magic stuff", can't you show us exactly how to reproduce the bug? In particular, what does your reST markup look like?

Comment: @mzjn: My ReST is not interesting at all, it's simply an automodule directive for the respective module. Also, everything worked fine with a pure Python-class. It works like this, sphinx uses the `inspect` module to introspect functions and classes for arguments. If it can't use `inspect` because it detects a built-in or C extension it will try and get the signature from the first line of the docstring. However, this fallback was only added for functions, and forgotten for classes, hence my bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug, I added a bug report and a fix here:

[https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/866/sphinx-doesnt-check-an-**init**-docstring#comment-1012906](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/866/sphinx-doesnt-check-an-__init__-docstring#comment-1012906)